# List view refresh in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view. When user scrolled till end, the i load more data. But its focus move to the first row of the listview. I want that the focused row should not be changed when list is updated. For example if i am in 10th position on the list. When list refreshed , i should remain on 10th. How to achieve it?

Comment: How do you update the list? Do you recreate the adapter? If yes, that can be the root cause. In my app I update the data only and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. And the list view remains on the same scroll position as before.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the programatically scrolling the listview by using `setSelection()` method work for you? Or are you looking to do something else?

Comment: setSelection() is not working properly. I am looking like when i am at the end of the list. The new items added then it should be feel like they are added at the end where i am currently. Not to feel life refresh